# Karaf Configuration: Environment variable mapping for properties containing minus sign

Tags: config, apache-karaf

I have a Karaf configuration file where property names contain a minus sign.

*my.file.cfg*

```
my-group.my-property=42
myGroup.myOtherProperty=42
```

When I try to redefine this property via env variable `MY_FILE_MY_GROUP_MY_PROPERTY` or `MY_FILE_MYGROUP_MYPROPERTY`, Karaf ignores the environment variable.

How can I override Karaf property values which have minus signs in their key?

Note that `MY_FILE_MYGROUP_MYOTHERPROPERTY` works like a charm. So the minus signs are the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: it is impossible to use environment variables in order to override **properties containing minus signs** in Karaf cfg property names. Dots become underscores, everything else gets converted to uppercase. There is no mapping for minus signs in environment var names.

Also note that the property name must be prefixed with the name of the cfg file followed by underscore, where the file name may contain dots which get converted to underscores, too.

Source: https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_environment_variables_system_properties